# My loop is not making the concatenation it should

Tags: r

I'm working trying to create a function capable of translating letters coming from an 8 character string (such as AAARLAA) into 20 bit code (10000000...) and then concatenating the results so from an 8 character string I obtain a 160 integer vector (in which each 20 number correspond to a letter).

This is my script

```
  octamer_encoding <- function(octamero){

  resultado_palabras <- vector("integer", length(octamero))
  
  A = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  R = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  N = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  D = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  C = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  E = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  Q = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  G = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  H = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  I = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  L = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  K = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  M = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  F = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  P = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
  S = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
  T = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
  W = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
  Y = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
  V = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
  
  numeros <- rbind(A,R,N,D,C,E,Q,G,H,I,L,K,M,F,P,S,T,W,Y,V)
  letras <- c('A','R','N','D','C','E','Q','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V')
  
  n = length(octamero)
  h = length(letras)
  
    for (j in 1:n){
      for (k in 1:h){
        if ((substring(octamero, first = j, last = j)) ==  (letras[k])){
          resultado_palabras <- c(resultado_palabras, numeros[k,])
        }
      }
    }
  
  return(resultado_palabras)
}
```

For some reason the result I obtain is only a 20 number vector, corresponding to the first letter of the string, meaning that the loop is not working to concatenate the different results, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: is the input octamero a string? in that case you need to use `nchar` instead of `length`

Comment: Could you post desired results as in `octamer_encoding(<your_argument>)` and the desired outcome?

Answer (score 4):

## Code Review

There are a couple of changes you need to do.
You should see them below:

```
octamer_encoding <- function(octamero){
 
 resultado_palabras <- c() ######### EDIT 1: YOU NEED TO CREATE AN EMPTY VECTOR FIRST
 
 A = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 R = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 N = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 D = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 C = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 E = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 Q = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 G = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 H = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 I = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 L = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 K = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 M = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 F = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
 P = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
 S = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)
 T = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
 W = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
 Y = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0)
 V = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
 
 numeros <- rbind(A,R,N,D,C,E,Q,G,H,I,L,K,M,F,P,S,T,W,Y,V)
 letras <- c('A','R','N','D','C','E','Q','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V')
 
 n = nchar(octamero) ############ EDIT 2: nchar instead of length.
 h = length(letras)
 
 for (j in 1:n){
  for (k in 1:h){
   if ((substring(octamero, first = j, last = j)) ==  (letras[k])){
    resultado_palabras <- c(resultado_palabras, numeros[k,])
   }
  }
 }
 
 return(unname(resultado_palabras))
}
```

---

## More compact

Also, I took the liberty to simplify your code to help you out:

```
octamer_encoding2 <- function(octamero){
 
 letras <- c('A','R','N','D','C','E','Q','G','H','I','L','K','M','F','P','S','T','W','Y','V')
 numeros <- diag(1, length(letras))
 colnames(numeros) <- letras
 c(numeros[,strsplit(octamero, "")[[1]]])
 
}

octamer_encoding("AAARLAA")
#>   [1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#>  [46] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#>  [91] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#> [136] 0 0 0 0 0
```

It does exactly the same but it is more compact.

And faster:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(octamer_encoding("AAARLAA"),
                               octamer_encoding2("AAARLAA"))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                          expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#>   octamer_encoding("AAARLAA") 604.3 632.95 735.284  673.2 760.70 1278.1   100
#>  octamer_encoding2("AAARLAA")  17.5  19.75  31.425   24.3  36.95  132.8   100
```

---

## Different encoding

If you are interested in a different (and more compact) encoding for your `letras`, you can use just 5 digits to identify 20 different letters.

You could define `numeros` as follow:

```
library(binaryLogic)
l <- length(letras)
numeros <- +simplify2array(as.binary(seq_len(l), n = ceiling(logb(l,2))))
colnames(numeros) <- letras
numeros
#>      A R N D C E Q G H I L K M F P S T W Y V
#> [1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
#> [2,] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
#> [3,] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
#> [4,] 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
#> [5,] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org):

```
library("tidyverse")
octamer_encoding <- function(x, collapse_chr = "") {
    vec_ltrs <- unlist(strsplit(x, split = ""))
    paste0(map_chr(
        .x = vec_ltrs,
        .f = function(row_letter = .x) {
            desired_row <- which(rownames(numeros) == row_letter)
            paste0(numeros[desired_row,], collapse = collapse_chr)
        }
    ), collapse = collapse_chr)
}
```

### Notes

- `numerous` corresponds to the object given in the original question:

  ```
  numeros <- rbind(A,R,N,D,C,E,Q,G,H,I,L,K,M,F,P,S,T,W,Y,V)
  ```

## Results

```
octamer_encoding("AAARLAA")
"10000000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000010000000001000000000000000000010000000000000000000"
```

*With space between resulting numbers.*

```
octamer_encoding("AAARLAA", collapse_chr = " ")
"1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
```

## More compact version

Using `~` syntax

```
octamer_encoding_compact <- function(x, collapse_chr = "") {
    paste0(map_chr(
        .x = unlist(strsplit(x, split = "")),
        .f = ~ paste0(numeros[rownames(numeros) == .x, ], collapse = collapse_chr)
    ),
    collapse = collapse_chr)
}
```

---

It's also wroth clarifying that with respect to:

> I obtain a 160 integer vector ...

This only works for arguments starting with "A" for anything else as

```
all.equal(as.integer("0001"), as.integer("01"))
```

will produce `TRUE`. So, more likely, you are interested in a character vector. If it's really crucial for you to keep the results as integer you can *fudge* leading zeros like that:

```
tst_num <- 123
pretty_result <- function(x) {
    formatC(x,
            width = 20,
            format = "d",
            flag = "0")
}
pretty_result(tst_num)
# [1] "00000000000000000123"
```

Comment: @Edo It's defined in the OP's question and I didn't paste it for brevity. `numerous` sits in global environment that `purrr` will access. I'll add a note for clarity.